# Government survey that includes detailed job titles

Tags: data-request, usa, survey, economy

I'm looking for a U.S. government data source that provides detailed or "raw" job titles alongside the usual standardized occupations (e.g. Census, SOC, or O*NET occupation codes). Here's the catch: **There must be some indication of how many people are in each job-title/code pair.**

I'm aware of [various](http://www.census.gov/people/io/methodology/indexes.html) [match files](http://www.bls.gov/soc/materials.htm) and [indexes](http://www.onetcenter.org/database.html?p=3#occ) that pair standardized codes with more detailed job titles, but none of them give a hint about the *relative frequency of each title within each code* (respondent count, or individual weighted records), which is really what I'm after.

The reason I ask for a government source is that I want the results to be as close to an unbiased random sample as possible.